# How to have different env files in Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, axios, environment-variables, next.js

I want to dynamically switch the base url of the external backend API on changing the environment.
E.g `.env.local=local.com, .env.staging=staging.com, .env.production=production.com`

For this I'm using axios for API call and I'm using the instance of axios in which baseURL is dependent on the current environment of the project.
e.g.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

And my scripts in `package.json` is as follows:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "dev:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next dev",
        "dev:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next build",
        "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next start",
        "start:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production next start"
 },
```

But it is always loading the .env.development and the axiosInstance is not getting the baseUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my approx understanding of the question, just sharing my input.

- Next js automatically fetches env variables as per the environment. So the
  different kind of scripts you have added might not be needed
- in local, next js will always load from `.env.local` file - [refer doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables). if you need to test out staging/production settings, replace the values in .env.local
- it is better to not commit env files to github, so for production checkout `Environment variables` section in vercel under project settings where we can add the required env variables